# bundle identifier differs from prior bundle identifier, can't change name back to original one

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundleidentifier

Well I know its incorrect, because the name of my app has a lowercase letter rather then an uppercase one. and when i attempt to change it in summary it says cannot be moved because a file with the same name exists, when I can't find it. Any help would help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your display name in the info .plist

Comment: where can I find the info.plst, Is it in show package contents?

Comment: you should find Supporting Files in the your project.